# Why was MLP Classifier deprecated in Apache Mahout?

Tags: neural-network, mahout

I am wondering why MultiLayerPerceptron http://apache.github.io/mahout/0.10.1/docs/mahout-mr/index.html?org/apache/mahout/classifier/mlp/MultilayerPerceptron.html and all classes within MLP Package of Apache Mahout were deprecated. This was done as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1676. The JIRA issue doesn't mention about any reasons for doing so. I was planning to use this classifier in my project but since it is deprecated I am now hesitant to use it. I don't see any alternative version of classes to be used as mentioned in the Javadoc . Does anyone using Mahout for MLP has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer this because it's basically off-topic. The mahout team considers that the MLP isn't used much by the community and it's painful to maintain so far. Thus they've decided to remove it since there exist other good implementations of it in other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks eliasah. I was just looking for that reason why it was discontinued. I thought it must be replaced with new set of classes that I am not aware of and couldn't find it online.